# Spring Integration Images for use in Visio

Tags: spring, visio, apache-camel, spring-integration

Does anyone know where some Spring style integration images can be found for use in Visio - just a stencil or where one could possible download the images used in the Spring Integration designer GUI as seen here: http://blog.springsource.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/si-sts-editor.png

FYI for anyone else interested there are these EIP stencils for Visio http://eaipatterns.com/downloads.html .

However I was hoping to use the ones that are used in the Spring Integration GUI to keep things consistent.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When You download and install [SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts), it has a file: `$STS_HOME/plugins/com.springsource.sts.config.ui_<version>.jar`.

When You unpack it with standard unzip tool, inside You'll find a folder `icons/integration`. That's where all images from [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) GUI editor are.

Comment: uptodate info:
for `spring-tool-suite-3.1.0.RELEASE-e4.2-win32.zip` images placed in `springsource\sts-3.1.0.RELEASE\plugins\org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.ui_3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE.jar\icons\integration\`

Answer (score 1):

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide
# any icons
git ls-files "*/icons/*"
# integration icons: 
git ls-files plugins/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.ui/icons/integration


valid for: df2c295 > 20 hours ago (HEAD, origin/master, origin/HEAD, master)
```

P.S. beware licensing

Answer (score 0):

The images of Spring integration are part of STS bundle. You can extract them from the bundle using simple bash commands:

```
BASE=https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/tree/master/plugins/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.ui/icons/integration/

RAW=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/master/plugins/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.config.ui/icons/integration/

curl "$BASE" | cheerio "a.js-directory-link" | sed "s;^;$RAW;" | xargs -I {} curl -O {}
```

Without the need to clone the original repository. My previous answer works on the local cloned repo.

Script uses cheerio CLI, you can donwload and install from npm. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio-cli